# Simple SSIS Package Failed User does not exist or has not permission

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, permissions

- I created and build SSIS Package with "Transfer SQL Server Objects
  Task".
- I Copied the package.dtsx to network folder with permissions    set
  to everyone.
- I created the SSIS Job where i set path to that   package.
- I am owner of source and destination database too.
- Package run as 32b.

But Job is failing. What can be wrong ? Why it is searching my credentials COMPANY\MYUSERNAME when the job is executed as COMPANY\SERVICEJOBACCOUNT ? (which also has access to the databases). Thank you

**Error is following**

```
Execution failed with the following error: 
"ERROR : errorCode=0 description=Cannot find the user 'COMPANY\MYUSERNAME', 
because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the connection string in the SSIS package. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that job needed to has an access to the default folder (on the server)

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server\Smo
```

My colleage solve it and according to him it is some kind of bug which is patched in newer version of SQL Server.